# How to change a variable?

Tags: analysis

I have this equation: $-u''(t)+cu'(t)+\lambda u(t)=f(t,u(t))$ how to change the variable  $u$ to get rid of the quantity $c u'(t)$ such that $c,\lambda>0$

i want to obtain something like $-v''+(brrr) v=f(t,...v)..$

Thank you

Comment: $-v''+(brrr)v$... is the stiffness term cold?

Comment: lol no it is a constant

Answer (score 0):

If you let 
$$
v(t) = e^{\frac{c}{2}t} u(t) 
$$
and divide the resulting equation by $e^{\frac{c}{2}t}$
then then equation becomes 
$$
-v^{\prime\prime} + \left( \lambda + \frac{c}{2} - \frac{c^2}{4} \right) v = f(t,e^{\frac{c}{2}t}v)
$$
which is the form you wanted.

How do you "guess" that factor of $e^{\frac{c}{2}t}$?

The general method is to let $u(t) = g(t) v(t)$ for some arbitrary function $g(t)$ and write 
$u^{\prime} = g v^{\prime}  + g^{\prime} v$ and $u^{\prime\prime} = g v^{\prime\prime} + 2 g^{\prime} v^{\prime} + g^{\prime\prime} v$ in the original equation. When you then demand that the coefficient of $v^{\prime}$ disappear, you get a differential equation, in this case 
$$
g^{\prime} = \frac{c}{2} g
$$
Any non-zero solution of that equation is your useful multiplication factor.

Comment: Thank you but i think that is $-v^{\prime\prime} + \left( \lambda + \frac{c^2}{2} - \frac{c^2}{4} \right) v = f(t,e^{\frac{c}{2}t}v)$ no ? thank you

Comment: $-v^{\prime\prime} + \left( \lambda + \frac{c^2}{2} - \frac{c^2}{4} \right) v = f(t,e^{\frac{-c}{2}t}v) e^{\frac{-c}{2}t}$ no ???